# Help reading an 1804 handwritten note about Kamchatka

Tags: handwriting, kurrent, paleography

[image: Image legend]

I have a small paleographical problem here: reading the quickly written key to an [1804 illustration of Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky](https://catalog.shm.ru/entity/OBJECT/2168537?query=106185&index=4). I think I can recognize about half of the words:

***A**. ein ...
**a**. Commandanten...
**B**. der ...
**b**. ... [der Amerikanische Compagna](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russl%C3%A4ndisch-Amerikanische_Kompagnie)
**c**. ...
**d**. ein Casernen
**e**. ein ... Batterie
**f**. ... oder ... [Nadezda](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadeschda_(Schiff,_1800)).*

Could you fine folks please help me fill in the blanks?

Comment: I can't load the illustration. The browser times out when trying to access the link. My reading would be "A. die Briefe a. Commandanten XXX B. der Lagolberg, welcher in der YYY ZZZ mit A ..." . Perhaps I could make more sense out of it, if I could actually see the illustration, which must have A, B, a, b, c.... written in it.

Comment: a probably is "Commandantenhaus"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It reads:

> A. die Kirche
> a Commandantenhaus
> B. der Kegelberg welcher in der anderen<sup>1</sup> Tafel<sup>2</sup> mit A bezeichnet ist
> b. das Warenlager der Amerikanischen Compagnie
> c. das Lazareth
> d. die Casernen
> e die neue Batterie,
> f der Weltumseegler oder die Nadegda<sup>5</sup>

<sup>1</sup> The character after "a" is, I believe, a struck out "l" and must be ignored.

<sup>2</sup> The "other table" or illustration ought to be [this one](https://catalog.shm.ru/entity/OBJECT/2168536?index=0&paginator=entity-set&entityType=OBJECT&entityId=2168537&attribute=like_predm), "Tab. II" where a hill in the bottom center is labelled "A" without a corresponding note in the key. (Both illustrations are by Tilesius, a participant in the circumnavigation of the globe aboard the *Nadezhda*.)

<sup>3</sup> This proper name written, as usual, in Latin characters rather than Kurrent, reads "Nade**g**da". You are doubtlessly correct in identifying this as the name of the globe-circumnavigating ship (*Weltumseegler*) Nadezhda.
**EDIT:** As `@tobi_s` helpfully points out in the comments, "The g in Nadegda is quite intentional and represents the ​/⁠ʒ⁠/​ sound (cyrillic ж) which in German only appears in French loan words -- where the letter g is used (Sabotage, Blamage etc)."

---

And here the requested entries from [Table II](https://catalog.shm.ru/entity/OBJECT/2168536?index=0&paginator=entity-set&entityType=OBJECT&entityId=2168537&attribute=like_predm):

> a Commandanten wohnung
> e die Salzsiederey<sup>4</sup>
> [building with cross] das Begräbniß bey dem Heidenfluß pagana retschka<sup>5</sup>

<sup>4</sup> i.e. the saltworks.

<sup>5</sup> "pagana" Lat. for "heathen", "речка" Russ. for "small river", in German: "Heidenfluss".

Comment: Thank you marquinho, this is great! It seems you are correct that the elements link the two illustrations. If you could also tell me how Tilesius defined e, a, and the churchy symbol, in Tab. II, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @AaronBrick With pleasure!

Comment: @marquinho I should think that "Nadegda" is in fact not what the author wanted to write. In Sütterlin, the character z also has a loop, so it might just be that the upper part of the z has been tilted, which would also match the fact that the circle is not closed.

Comment: Compare the z in bezeichnet. The g in Nadegda is quite intentional and represents the ​/⁠ʒ⁠/​ sound (cyrillic ж) which in German only appears in French loan words -- where the letter g is used (Sabotage, Blamage etc).

Comment: @tobi_s Great and convincing explanation.

Comment: @tobi_s you're probably right since a german wouldn't transcribe nadezda with a z, now that I think of it, but rather sh or sch.